# Windows Event Forwarding and Sysmon

Tags: windows, logging, monitoring

I'm dealing with a bit of an issue relating to WEF and sysmon

I have the collector server setup and 2 domain controllers are configured via GPO to send events to WEF collector.

It is configured via Source initiated but it seems there might be something missing in the configuration.

I used https://www.syspanda.com/index.php/2017/03/01/setting-up-windows-event-forwarder-server-wef-domain-gpo-deployment-part-33/ config guide but excluded step 4.

Step 1: Create WinRM Service and set it to start automatically

Launch your group policy utility and perform the following:

Right click your computer OU and
Create GPO in this domain, and link it here
Provide a name (WEF Deployment) , click OK
Right click your newly created GPO WEF Deployment and select Edit
Navigate to Computer Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > “New > Service”
Startup: AutomaticService
Name: WinRMService
Action: Start service
Click Apply

Step 2: Provide Event Log Reader Access

In this step we will add the Network Service & Event Forwarder Server (WindowsLogCollector) to the Event Log Readers and Groups. This will give our WEF server (WindowsLogCollector) access to your domain endpoint event logs.

Right click your WEF Deployment GPO and select Edit
Computer Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > right click > “New Group”
Action: Update
Group Name: Event Log Readers
Members: NETWORK SERVICE
Domain\WindowsLogCollector$
Apply > OK

Step 3: Adding WEF Server Subscription address
This will allow our endpoints to enroll to our WindowsLogCollector subscriptions.

Right click your WEF Deployment GPO and select Edit
Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Event Forwarding > Configure target Subscription Manager >
Set to EnableShow: Server=http://WindowsLogCollector.domain.COM:5985/wsman/SubscriptionManager/WEC

*Step 4: Allow Remote server Management through WinRM*

Right click your WEF Deployment GPO and select Edit
Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Remote Management (WinRM) > WinRMService > Allow Remote Server Management through WinRM
Set: EnableiPv4 Filter: *   (or you may enter just the IP address of your WindowsLogCollector)
IpV6 Filter: *  (you may uncheck this)

Is there something missing after applying log reader access? As it still says **source computers is 0**

Perhaps a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Step 4: Allow Remote server Management through WinRM
This step is necessary and without the applied wildcard filters logs will not send to target.

Make sure to also create an inbound firewall rile in the GPO on port 5985 TCP

All is working and logs are ingesting.